# What’s the meaning or function of ‘ever’ in the example?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It was the best evening of Harry's life, better than winning at
>   Quidditch, or Christmas, or knocking out mountain trolls... he would
>   never, **ever** forget tonight. (Harry Potter)

What’s the meaning or function of ‘ever’ in this sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Saying "never, ever" is more emphatic than saying "never" alone.  Apart from emphasis, the meaning remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

The relevant OED definition here is:

> ***ever** adv. throughout all past or **all future time**; perpetually*.

...but it's worth bearing in mind that since ***never*** derives from *ne- (not) **ever***, it's really just repetition for the sake of emphasis. Related usages include:

> [never in a month of Sundays](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22henceforward%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22never%20in%20a%20month%20of%20Sundays%22&oq=%22never%20in%20a%20month%20of%20Sundays%22&gs_l=serp.3...453519.462724.1.463060.45.39.0.0.0.5.150.2680.35j4.39.0...0.0...1c.1.4.psy-ab.1opcJ0SzAbQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42661473,d.d2k&fp=1128f60b3d5eaf47&biw=1381&bih=848)
>    [never in a million years](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22henceforward%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&gs_rn=4&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=rbAxNIbLgI2DgWXHp2XO3A&ds=bo&pq=%22never%20in%20a%20month%20of%20sundays%22&cp=25&gs_id=al&xhr=t&q=%22never%20in%20a%20million%20years%22&es_nrs=true&pf=p&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22never%20in%20a%20million%20years%22&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42661473,d.d2k&fp=1128f60b3d5eaf47&biw=1381&bih=848&bs=1)

Comment: I have no idea why this was voted down--it's a good answer.  +1.

Comment: @snailplane: Thanks for sparing me the ignominy of having a negative net score! I can't see any *valid* reason either, but perhaps it's "payback" for one of my all-too-often acerbic comments elsewhere. Or, as happens from time to time, I'm just in the sites of a serial-downvoter troll. Every month or so I suddenly get a rep boost when the mods identify and delete a troll's account, so I try not to take unexplained downvotes too seriously.